# Clustering Data of 8 dimensions

Tags: r, data-visualization, cross-validation, data-mining

I am working on a data clustering and don't know how I can achieve it with R !
I am working on a data set of 50 observations each of 8 variables. What i want is to have clusters gathering the observations with high homogeneity. 
Kmeans isn't giving me that in terms of data visualization !
How can I do that ?

Comment: Note that **preprocessing is essential** for k-means. If your 8 variables are of different data type and scale, then k-means will not work. k-means does work for multi-dimensional data, but if it is not well preprocessed, **one variable may completely determine the outcome**. So do make sure to spend enough time on preprocessing your data, scaling, feature weighting, etc.

Comment: I don't think the scale is the problem in my case. But I do find it difficult to have "good" clusters. Since my Dataset contains a lot of small enterprises, Kmeans assigns the large ones to size-one clusters. Do you think it's more interesting to work with ratios (to standardize the variables in a way) instead or should I just go with the z-score ?

Comment: Most likely, your attributes aren't linear, so you do need to (non-linearly) carefully scale your attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little unsure what you mean by "clusters gathering the observations with high homogeneity." If what you mean is you expect most people to respond similarly across all dimensions (e.g. a high Chronbach's $\alpha$), clustering will do that, but only if your data has observations with high homogeneity. If what you mean is you want high homogeneity clusters (e.g. small within cluster sum of squares), that is also completely dependent on your data. If your have highly variable data, the clusters will naturally be highly variable until you get up to creating large numbers of clusters.

One possible thing to think about is whether K-means is the best clustering approach for your data. If you have binary or otherwise categorical dimensions (e.g. has pets/does not have pets), k-means is generally not the way to go, and you may want to look into k-medians, hierarchical clustering with manhattan distances, or any of several other alternatives.

If you provide more info about your specific problem, I (we) can provide better suggestions.

Comment: Hello le_andrew and thanks for answering. To make it clearer, I have 50 enterprises (each defined by a number of financial variables: EBIT, Debts,..) . I want a clustering method that could gather these enterprises in groups, and in fine get a visualization of those groups (in a graph or smth !) I tried K means but what I get is groups of clusters (each depending on 2 variables at a time) it's like he's decided to combine the variables ((Turnover, Debts) (Turnover, EBIT) (EBIT, Debts)...) and do the clustering in a bidimensional way.

Comment: I don't think its that its doing the clusters in a bidimensional way, its that you can't create a graph with 8 dimensions. You can only create multiple graphs each with 2 dimensions (or you can simulate 3, but thats besides the point). Have you looked at the a within group sum of squares plot with number of clusters on the X axis (I always call these scree plots, but I don't think they are technically scree plots). If so, does your solution account for most of the variance?

Comment: Ok, No I just want to make sure that these clusters take into consideration all the variables. Does Kmean do that by definition ?

Comment: It does take into consideration all variables you tell it to, but since it is computing a distance, the scales of your variables matter. For instance, if you have 2 variables, one a proportion and one a percentage, a qualitative difference along the proportion axis may be larger than along the percentage axis butkmeans will think the difference is larger along the percentage axis because the scale is larger. Anony-Mousse's comment raises the same point. It is common to standardize (e.g. z-score) your variables before running k-means though there are other concerns to consider as well.